# Bing Maps V8 SDK - Get drawn shapes

Tags: bing-maps

I have a Bing map with drawing manager enabled for users to draw shapes (mostly one polygon at a time). I want to be able to get the details of the drawn polygon so I can save it in the database.

The below function can access the shapes but returns the coordinates only

```
function getShapes()   
{
    var shapes = drawingManager.getPrimitives();
    if (shapes && shapes.length > 0) 
        {
            var rings = shapes[0].getRings();
            alert('Retrieved ' + rings[0] + ' from the drawing manager.');
        } 
    else 
        {
            alert('No shapes in the drawing manager.');
        }
}
```

result is:
Retrieved [MapLocation (35.17314901376581, 44.72432011035158)],[MapLocation (35.10324034213123, 44.73015659716798)],[MapLocation (35.12346106720259, 44.90525120166017)],[MapLocation (35.18633788986748, 44.88362186816408)],[MapLocation (35.17314901376581, 44.72432011035158)] from the drawing manager.

How can I get the exact drawn shape details not just the coordinates?

Answer (score 1):

Remove `getRings()` and you will have the shape object. The Get Rings function retudrrns the coordinates of a polygon.